# help with AをBに回せる and 騎

Tags: grammar, meaning

This is a small part of the dialogue of Fate/stay night:

> あれ一体{いったい}だけで 他{ほか}の六騎{ろっき}を敵{てき}に回{まわ}せるぞ

Why they use 騎 as a counter for Servants?

Many times I have seen this construction:

> AをBに回せる

What is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here 騎 is used as a generic counter for "fighters". Originally, 騎 is a counter for cavalries, and using 騎 to actually count cavalries is of course rare these days. But idiomatic words like [一騎打ち](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E4%B8%80%E9%A8%8E%E6%89%93%E3%81%A1) or [一騎当千](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%80%E9%A8%8E%E5%BD%93%E5%8D%83) are still very common today. Probably the author had 一騎当千 in his mind, and thought it was nice to use the counter 騎 to describe this situation. I can't say it's common, but I feel it's a nice word choice.
- ～を敵に回す is a common idiomatic phrase that means "to make an enemy of ～". [Examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%95%B5%E3%81%AB%E5%9B%9E%E3%81%99&ref=sa). 回す can mean "to put/move someone/something in some place", "to assign" (eg, 給料を貯金に回す, 社員を開発担当に回す).