# Historical meaning of an army's name in Sengoku era 美濃八千騎

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension, history, light-novel

美濃八千騎

I read a historical novel with Sengoku era setting , and there's a character mentioned about this name of an army. If you know about it's historical meaning please explain.

Context is an enemy's captain yelling at his troops when they can't fight against the protagonist.

Enemy Captain「ええい！何をやっておるのだ！たかが山賊に後れを取るなど、日の本最強である美濃八千騎の名の穢れであるぞ！」

Comment: Do you understand the literal translation but want to know what this phrase meant in actual history? If that's the case, it would be off-topic on this site.

Comment: This is partly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36326/43676